# accessing dynamic property when calling Action....MVC

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

I have an Action method that returns JSON, for brevity, I excluded code. :

```
public ActionResult SetMasterLocation(string masterValue)
{
    json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(masterLocation);
    return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I need to call this method and access the JSON string that gets returned:

```
 var jVendors = SetMasterLocation(masterValue);
```

When I run it and inspect the output, I see the JSON string in a dynamic property called Data:

[image]

[image]

But if I try to access data like this, the app will not compile because the compiler says Cannot resolve symbol 'Data':

```
      var jVendors = SetMasterLocation(masterValue);
        var data = jVendors.Data;
```

How do I access the Data property at runtime?

Comment: Where do you call the method `var jVendors = SetMasterLocation(masterValue);`?

Comment: Also, why don't you simply return a string rather than an ActionResult if you want to read the json as a string?

Comment: @Liam - I ended up doing that, but i know I had done what i was trying to do in a previous project. The answer is below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return `JsonResult`

```
 return new JsonResult()
 {
    Data = someData,
    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
 };
```

Then, you can access `Data` property of the result

Comment: Thats it! Thank you Mike